# MudDatePicker DefaultValue plus DateChange

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I want to use *MudDatePicker* element in a way where I need to be able to set a default value on load but at the same time define a `onChange` event for it. I am trying to do this but error says:

> The component parameter is used two or more times for this component

Is there a way I can do this?

```
<MudDatePicker @bind-Date="@DefaultValue.Value" Label="Date" DateChanged="OnDateChange"
        Required="true" Class="mb-3" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a two-way binding in Blazor i.e. `@bind-Date="date"`, you can convert it to a one-way binding with a change event which must set the value. The two-way binding is just syntax sugar and will do the same behind the scene.

```html
<MudDatePicker Date="@_date" Label="Date" DateChanged="OnDateChange"
        Required="true" Class="mb-3" />

@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

@code {
    DateTime? _date = new DateTime(2021, 12, 24);

    void OnDateChange(DateTime? newDate)
    {
        _date=newDate;
        // here you can do something when the date changes.
        Snackbar.Add($"Date changed to {_date}");
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is a snippet which you can play around with: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mYcPFPvLnlyEHeOF

Comment: Didn't know about the MudBlazor playground, very handy tool.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `DateChanged="OnDateChange"` and change `@bind-Date="DefaultValue.Value"` to `@bind-Date="DefaultValue"`. For the property `DefaultValue` create a getter and setter. Because you have two way binding using `@bind-Date="DefaultValue"`, the setter part gets called every time the value is changed.

I've added some sample code below:

```
DateTime? _defaultValue = DateTime.Now;

private DateTime? DefaultValue
        {
            get => _defaultValue;
            set
            {
                _defaultValue = value;
                OnDateChange();
            }
        }
```