# MudTimePicker bind value and also change EventCallback

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I have been bashing my head on this for a while, I wonder if I'm missing something obvious. I'm trying to bind a `TimeSpan?` to the `MudTimePicker`, while also triggering a method whenever a change in its value occurs. The timepicker looks like the following:

```cs
<MudTimePicker Label="Time duration"
               HelperText="Enter any numeric value as hours:minutes:seconds"
               Editable="true"
               @bind-Time="@Timespan"
               ImmediateText="true"
               Placeholder="hh:mm:ss"
               Mask="@(new DateMask("00:00:00"))"/>
```

If you edit the time via the control, the event gets triggered, however, if you manually edit the time (e.g. by typing a valid number in the field), no change is detected. This is true even after pressing Enter.

This question is similar to [another about the MudDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749787/muddatepicker-defaultvalue-plus-datechange), but that one uses one-way binding and [the docs of `MudTimePicker` explicitly say](https://www.mudblazor.com/components/timepicker#basic-usage):

> Note: Always use the two-way binding @bind-Time to bind to a field of type TimeSpan?

I have tried, without success:

- binding with `@bind-Time` and `@bind-Time:after`. Binding fails (i.e. no value is set from the user input) if the `@bind-Time:after` is present
- separately binding `Time="@someTimespan"` and `TimeChanged="@onTimespanChanged"` (binding fails, as expected given the note above)
- Use a backing field and invoke the method during `set`, i.e. the following (also here binding doesn't happen for me – this is also against Blazor guidelines and generates a BL0007 warning):

  ```cs
  private TimeSpan? timespan;

  [Parameter]
  public TimeSpan? Timespan 
  {
      get { return timespan; }
      set { timespan = value; OnTimespanChanged(); } 
  }
  ```

Comment: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkGHvFFGiHjLlKPI it's working as expected. In the `TimeChanged` handler method are you assigning the new time received back to the variable assigned to `Time`?

Comment: @RBee Thank you for your test. Indeed that works, I added my usage for clarification. If you try that, it doesn't work. Narrowing it down, it seems to be an issue when `Mask` is being used. As a workaround, I'm switching to TextField with a Mask and a conversion to TimeSpan, [similar to the example in the docs](https://www.mudblazor.com/components/textfield#mask). That's probably the way to go, although I find it confusing why it doesn't work here.

Comment: It's still working. first snippet [time & timechanged](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYwxvPFxfPsJOASK) second snippet [bind-Time](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkGdbPvRfbivWcbi) , can you create a snippet using the same site ensuring the error is there. Also you're supposed to use the TimeFormat property not DateMask, DateMask is for dates i.e. dd:mm:yy

Comment: In timeformat you can show am/pm using `tt` in the TimeFormat like `TimeFormat="hh:mm:ss tt"`

Comment: Thanks @RBee, very useful examples. I think the error lied in the incorrect usage of `DateMask`, at least in one case. A reworking of your example with [Time & Timechanged](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEmdvvbIdZVhpPAc) shows indeed the method being triggered (see also console output). However, I couldn't make it work with this reworked [`@bind-Time` example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckQnbbleHjWZYNWI). If I'm not mistaken, even in [your original snippet for @bind-time](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkGdbPvRfbivWcbi) the change method actually didn't trigger?

Comment: This is the solution I landed on: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QuQnFbFyecQDGfPC. This uses separate Time & TimeChanged and a `PatternMask` to enforce manual input pattern. I still wonder what I am doing wrong in the [@bind-Time example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckQnbbleHjWZYNWI), because it appears to me as still not triggering the change.

Comment: You need to look up how blazor `@bind`directive works, in short using `Time` & `TimeChanged` is the shorthand of `@bind-Time` where you can use the handler method that you attach to the `TimeChanged` for custom logic. When you use `@bind-Time` the handler method is not going to be fired because you're basically telling blazor I just want this variable to be tracked with no other custom logic.

Comment: For your use case you definitely need to use Time and TimeChanged not `@bind-Time` because you need to perform additional logic when the time is changed. Can you add the Time & TimeChanged code that you tried before including the method that you attached to TimeChanged to the question, before when it didn't work.